# Configuring push notifications iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I used [Pushbots](https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/ios-configuration) to configure push notifications for my app. After I get the notification, I am able to put it into a UITableview. However the notification only appears after the user restarts the app. Is there a way to immediately add the notification text after the user gets it, or when the user clicks the notification?

In my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Pushbots sharedInstanceWithAppId:@"--myAppid--"];
    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] receivedPush:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // This method will be called everytime you open the app
    // Register the deviceToken on Pushbots
    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] registerOnPushbots:deviceToken];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Notification Registration Error %@", [error userInfo]);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //Handle notification when the user click it while app is running in background or foreground.
    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] receivedPush:userInfo];
    //NSLog(@"UserInfo: %@", userInfo);
    NSString *msg = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString *alertMsg = [msg valueForKey:@"alert"];
    //NSLog(@"Push Notification:%@",alertMsg);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:alertMsg forKey:@"ReceivedNotifications"];
    NSLog(@"Alert: %@", alertMsg);
}
```

In my `ViewController.m`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *notifTableView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *notif;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.notifTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.notifTableView.delegate = self;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *checkAlert = [[NSString alloc] init];
    checkAlert = [defaults stringForKey:@"ReceivedNotifications"];
    NSLog(@"Alert Message: %@", checkAlert);
    notif = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:checkAlert, nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return [notif count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
        cell.textLabel.text = [notif objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewController viewDidLoad method start listen to a NSNotification as below,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) 
        name:@"TestNotification"
        object:nil];
```

Add this `receiveNotification` to your ViewController as well. Inside this if condition you can reload the TableView.

```
- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // [notification name] should always be @"TestNotification"
    // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
    // as well.

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
}
```

Don't forget to remove the notification when you dealloc the ViewController,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Then from your AppDelegate once you receive a notification, post a Notification to `TestNotification` name

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
        object:nil]; //You can set object as nil or send the object you want to get from the ViewController
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the observer in dealloc

Answer (score -2):

try to use NSNoticationCenter same as DilumN said in his answer , when you receive the notification then reload the tableview in that method.

Comment: What was the point of this answer? It adds nothing to the answer you reference. You should delete this answer and up vote the answer you like.